# Finding by null field in Mongoose won't return the expected results

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to find in Mongoose with a field $ne: null, but it won't return the expected results.

**Code**

```
router.get('/service/products/all', function(req, res, next) {
    Product.find({ 'PMC18': {$ne: null} }, { prodCode: 1, prodName: 1, description: 1, PMC18: 1, inStock: 1 }, function (err, docs) {
        console.log(err);        
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    }).limit(50);    
});
```

**Results with no $ne: null query**

```
{ _id: '5816a7cd404dc92634bbb507',
    prodCode: '1038501090064',
    prodName: 'LISOMUC',
    description: '10 MG / ML XPE CX 50 FR PET AMB X 120 ML + COP (EMB HOSP)',
    PMC18: null }
```

**Result with $ne: null query**

```
{ _id: '5816a7cd404dc92634bbb507',
    prodCode: '1038501090064',
    prodName: 'LISOMUC',
    description: '10 MG / ML XPE CX 50 FR PET AMB X 120 ML + COP (EMB HOSP)',
    PMC18: null }
```

**Mongoose Product Schema**

```
_id: String,
prodCode: String,
prodName: String,
description: String,
EAN: String,
PMC18: Number,
manipulationCost: String,
profitRange: String,
inStock: Number,
group: Number
```

What am I missing?

Thank you all very much.

Comment: Every time I try to write some greetings like "Hey guys", it is cut off '-'

Comment: Regarding your comment: that's because greetings and salutations in questions are actively discouraged on SO. So you should also remove your "Thank you all very much." as well. The thought is appreciated, but it's just a way to keep the noise in the questions to a minimum.

Comment: Back to your question...the query works fine when I try it (empty result).

Comment: Well. Somehow that won't work. When I changed my PMC18 model to String, and compared $ne to '', it worked...

Comment: What's your MongoDB and Mongoose versions?

Comment: MongoDB: 3.2.x - Mongoose: latest (4.6.5)

Comment: Weird. Works fine here with those versions, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

`Product.find({ PMC18: {$ne: null} }, { prodCode: 1, prodName: 1, description: 1, PMC18: 1, inStock: 1 }, function (err, docs) {
        console.log(err);`

You are querying correctly,i think the problem is with quote,because I am not seeing any errors in given code as the unexpected  results you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Please test for add $exists: true in bellow code:

```
router.get('/service/products/all', function(req, res, next) {
    Product.find({ 'PMC18': {$exists: true, $ne: null} }, { prodCode: 1, prodName: 1, description: 1, PMC18: 1, inStock: 1 }, function (err, docs) {
        console.log(err);        
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    }).limit(50);    
});
```

Comment: I did it. Not the expected result yet.